# Laravel Autoloader(s): Different Behavior During Bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

In a Laravel 4.2 application, I have the following class file

```
#File: app/models/Hello.php
<?php
class Hello
{
}
```

Thanks to Laravel's autoloaders, I can instantiate this class in a route definition without issue.

```
Route::get('tutorial', function(){
    $o = new Hello;    
    var_dump(get_class($o));
});
```

However, if I attempt to instantiate the class in

```
bootstrap/start.php
```

PHP can't seems to find the class file, and I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Hello' not found in /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/start.php on line 15

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  241880  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.1130  1917640 require_once( '/path/to/laravel/bootstrap/start.php' )  ../index.php:35
```

Normally, I'd assume this is because all the autoloaders haven't been setup yet. However, if I peek at the autoloaders with `spl_autoload_functions` in both contexts, they contain the same four autoloaders (called at the end of `bootstrap/start.php`

```
var_dump(spl_autoload_functions());
```

This leaves me a little mystified as to why the autoloading works from my routes.php files, but not in `start/bootstrap.php`.  My assumption is *something else* happens that adds *some state* to one of the four autoloaders.  I'd like to know what that something else is, or, if I'm incorrect, how the autoloader works in one place but not the other.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/start/global.php#L18

Answer (score 0):

While Laravel's four autoloaders had been loaded, Laravel's main autoloader hadn't had any directories added to it yet with `ClassLoader::addDirectories`.

The best bet to use a class in the `bootstrap/start.php` file is to add that class (or class directory) to Composer's `classmap` property, and then regenerate the composer autoloader include files with

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```